# SQL variable assignment and comparison logic

Tags: mysql, mysql-variables

I am looking into the following mysql:

```
select num, @record, 
case 
    when @record = num then @count:=@count+1
    when @record <> @record:=num then @count:=1 end as n
from 
    Logs ,(select @count:=0,@record:=(SELECT num from Logs limit 0,1)) r
```

Where Logs table is like:

```
+----+-----+
| Id | Num |
+----+-----+
| 1  |  1  |
| 2  |  1  |
| 3  |  1  |
| 4  |  2  |
| 5  |  1  |
| 6  |  2  |
| 7  |  2  |
+----+-----+
```

And the outputs of the query is like:

```
 |num | @record | n   |
 ----------------------
 | 1  |     "1" | 1.0 |
 | 1  |     "1" | 2.0 | 
 | 1  |     "1" | 3.0 |
 | 2  |     "1" | 1.0 |
 | 1  |     "2" | 1.0 | 
 | 2  |     "1" | 1.0 | 
 | 2  |     "2" | 2.0 |
```

For the second and third row, I have hard time understand how is derived. For example, in row_1 (Id = 1), `@record = Num`, why n = 1 not 2?
In row_3,   `@record = Num`, why n = 3 not 2?

Is there only one @record global variable? or each num has its own @record variable?

Could anyone please help me to understand the @sql variable logic? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

MySQL evaluates the JOIN first i.e `@count=1` and `@record=1` before any rows are processed. First row's `num` is the same as the `@record` so `n` gets value of 1 (`@count+1`).

Second and third rows follow the same logic resulting values 2 and 3.

Fourth row resets the `@count` and puts new `num` into @record

and so on...

Answer (score 0):

The value of column n comes from @count, not @record.
@record is used to assign reset the @count to 1 when num is changed